# If a Table alias doesn't exist in another subquery, what is the point of creating them?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, alias

I have a table `flight` and I need to write an SQL query in mysql which returns the cheapest flight between two specific cities.

I attempted the following code

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
   FROM flight
   WHERE departure_airport = 'AMS' AND arrival_airport = 'JFK') AS subset
WHERE fare = (SELECT MIN(fare) FROM subset)
```

But this produced the following error.

> Table 'AIRLINE.subset' doesn't exist

After looking through solutions I figured out aliases are not available in the subsequent sub-queries that way, and managed to make the code run by changing it:

```
SELECT *
FROM flight
WHERE departure_airport = 'AMS' AND arrival_airport = 'JSK'
ORDER BY fare ASC
LIMIT 1
```

**This works.**
But I want to know how can I make the query run using previous method. Is it impossible to re-use a derived table? And if so, what is the point of forcing us to name an alias if we cannot use it.

Comment: You would use a CTE instead.  Those are available in MySQL starting with version 8.

Comment: Alternatively: Create subset as a view.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I want to know how can I make the query run using previous method. Is it impossible to re-use a derived table?"*

Well, no it's not impossible. If you specifically want to use the first query method, then you can do try the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM flight
WHERE fare = (SELECT MIN(fare)
              FROM   flight
              WHERE  departure_airport = 'AMS' AND arrival_airport = 'JFK');
```

But the above query will return all matching fare value regardless of the `departure_airport` and `arrival_airport`. And this doesn't require using *table aliases* because the subquery is referred to as value instead of a table.

> *"what is the point of forcing us to name an alias if we cannot use it?"*

Actually we can use it and we need alias for *virtual table*. But not in the way of your first query. A *virtual table* is a table we usually generate using a sub-query which in your case this:

```
(SELECT * 
   FROM flight
   WHERE departure_airport = 'AMS' AND arrival_airport = 'JFK')
```

You notice that when you do a data retrieval from a table you always start with `SELECT * FROM ...`. If the you don't assigned the subquery with any alias, do you expect a message like this?

> Error Code: 1146 Table '(SELECT * FROM flight WHERE departure_airport = 'AMS' AND arrival_airport = 'JFK')' doesn't exist

Then this attempt

```
WHERE fare = (SELECT MIN(fare) FROM **subset**)
```

is trying to obtain the value from a virtual table you've created. Inside the subquery is a different *dimension*.

Now, lets address your query condition. I'm assuming that you want to get the lowest fare from departure_airport = 'AMS' AND arrival_airport = 'JSK', correct? Then, why don't we do retrieve that using a single query? something like this:

```
SELECT   departure_airport,arrival_airport,MIN(fare) AS min_fare
FROM     flight
WHERE    departure_airport = 'AMS' AND arrival_airport = 'JFK'
GROUP BY departure_airport,arrival_airport;
```

How about using a sub-query but with a `JOIN`?

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM   flight AS f
JOIN  (SELECT   departure_airport,arrival_airport,MIN(fare) min_fare
       FROM     flight
       WHERE    departure_airport = 'AMS' 
       AND      arrival_airport = 'JFK'
       GROUP BY departure_airport,arrival_airport) AS subset
ON     f.departure_airport = subset.departure_airport 
AND    f.arrival_airport = subset.arrival_airport 
WHERE  f.fare = subset.min_fare;
```